# Google Bar Chart using hAxis.logScale - gridlines appear at regular intervals

Tags: google-visualization

I am creating a Google Bar Chart and have an outlier in the data.  I would like to use the logscale option to show the data - otherwise, the large data result overwhelms the smaller ones.  The logscale works effectively, but I am afraid the users will not notice the fact that it's a logscale, because the gridlines are at regular intervals.  If the look hard at the labels on those gridlines, they will realize that the scale is changing, but normally on a logscale chart, the gridlines would start getting closer together (at least on logscale graphing paper).

I've looked through the options and can't find anything that helps.  Can I specify the positions of each gridline in the hAxis?  Any thoughts?